# cannot load such file -- roadie/rails (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I get load error after upgrade to Rails 3.2.17 from 3.2.13.

```
gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- roadie/rails (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 0):

try installing ruby dev package
`sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev`

Comment: @Sivakumar- Once I got the same error, I got it solved by uninstalling `gem uninstall roadie-rails` 
`bundle install`
`bundle update` and `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev` it worked for me..sorry I don't know why it's not working for you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PieterGoosen - author commented on my answer, so I posted reply to it. If I need clarification I will definitely comment on his post